# How to add a header to the output of an awk command afterwards?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I create a file (output) from another file (input) using awk (skipping the header):

```
awk 'NR==1{next} $3==1 {print $1"\t"$2}' input > output
```

I then have header information I can only calculate afterwards, which I add using sed:

```
sed -i "1s/^/head1\thead2\n/" output
```

However, the sed is pretty slow, I'm wondering if there is a better way of  doing it? Like saving the awk result and then writing the file after I have the header information?

Comment: What holds you from changing `NR==1{next}` to `NR==1{printf "head1\thead2\n";next}` ???

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I don't have head1 and head2 until I've parsed the entire file.

Comment: OK.What is really head1 and head2? Maybe we can find another way...

Comment: The better way is to **use `ex`**, but I can't advise on how without more data on what "head" really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling, I found this question:
[Change the header in a huge file without rewriting the whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265904/change-the-header-in-a-huge-file-without-rewriting-the-whole-file).

To prevent having to rewrite the entire file when adding in the header, I printed a dummy header of a minimum amount of bytes (by padding with zeros) while creating the file:

```
awk 'NR==1{print "dummyhead100\tdummyhead20000"; next} $3==1 {print 
$1"\t"$2}' input > output
```

I then make a file (or string variable) with the new head as header.tsv, and replace the dummy header in-place (after making sure the dummy and new headers are the same number of bytes) using `dd`:

```
dd conv=notrunc obs=1 if=header.tsv of=output
```

This way `output` is edited in-place, and I don't have to wait for the whole file to be copied, or have to keep it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the body in the `output` file and the desired header in a file named `header` (`printf "head1\thead2\n" > header`), then you can insert the header with:

```
ed -s output <<< $'0r header\nw\nq'
```

The `-s` says to Suppress the diagnostic output (which would be how many bytes it read in from `output`, how many bytes it read in from `header`, and how many bytes it wrote out at the end).

The ed commands are:

- `0r header` - at line zero, read the contents of the file `header`
- `w` - write out the file
- `q` - quit ed

Answer (score 0):

Try with ***bash***:

```
echo -e "head1\thead2\n$(cat output)" > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out output
```

Comment: Won't the output file be clobbered?

Comment: Indeed, you might want to use a different filename for the final output file and the raw data file, so that you can simply `cat header corpus > output` once all of the sausage-making is done.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, changed via temp file

Comment: Unfortunately this means I will at one stage need 3 copies of the output file?

Comment: @Luce, ok, let's say it seemed less convenient for you. But you said *sed is pretty slow*, is it slower than 'sed'? I didn't test it. Have you test it for comparison?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I tried to test it, and ran out of disk space, lol. I realise I didn't specify that as a requirement, so thanks for your suggestion, it hadn't occurred to me to use echo.

Answer (score 0):

I would do in bash

```
{ echo -e "head1\thead2" ; cat output ; } > newoutput
```

compared to RomanPerekhrest's answer it will work properly even for very long files (his would load the file first into memory and then execute the echo; also bash has imho some maximum length of input)

Answer (score 0):

Looks a bit strange but it seems that works in my tests. You can make a test.

```
echo -e "$head1\t$head2\n" "$(<file5)" >file5
```

Test:

```
$ cat file5
home
help
$ echo -e "header1\theader2\n" "$(<file5)" >file5
$ cat file5
header1 header2
home
help
```